# mysql add index on varchar(500)

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, innodb

In one of my database tables , I have a varchar field with length 500. This filed is frequently used in `Where clause` of my queries and there are about 1000,000 records in the table.
Now to speed of such query , what should I do?

- Use InnoDB engine or MYISAM ?
- my current table engine is InnoDB. does it have a limitation on index size as my filed lenght is 500.
- Do I need *Full text indexing* ? (I should mention that I use this field on a simple equality comparison where clasue e.g : `WHERE my_field='bla bla bla...'`)

Answer (score 0):

When doing indexing with MySQL you need to think about weather you need a fulltext search. To my knowledge fulltext is only available in MyISAM. This will limit you to the database that you will need to use. You can find everything about those fulltext search queries [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

When we are talking about strings like "bla bla bla" then you would need a fulltext search anyway, i.e. MyISAM is your database of choice.

Comment: full text indexing is really needed for a simple equality comparison? Well actually I don't know what's the difference between full text indexing and simple indexing on a varchar field. would you tell me that? In fact InnoDB lets me to add simple index on it but it adds a 255 character limit I think...

Comment: @ali fulltext indexes are only useful if you do `%LIKE` (suffix) or `%LIKE%` (infix) queries. If you only ever do equality queries on that column, then a fulltext index won't help.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak : So is there another way to speed up such queries? for example adding a normal index?

Comment: well you could start out doing memcached if you really needed it to even faster.

Comment: @ali yes. A normal index will speed up queries on equality. A normal index should also speed up prefix queries. A normal index on the reverse text should also speed up suffix queries, but you might need to write the queries as such. If you are using infix queries, use a fulltext index.

Comment: @JanDvorak : So what to do with the index size limitation? I think it has a 255 character length restriction , while my field has 500 length. What happens if I add the normal index according to this point?

Comment: @ali if it won't let you add the full index, you can still try to add an index to `LEFT(col, 255)`. The planner still _should_ be able to use it.